# How to get a pointer from my NativeScript UIView for iOS?

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I am integrating an iOS framework (Vidyo https://developer.vidyo.io/#/documentation/4.1.25.30) from a custom NativeScript plugin. I am able to instantiate iOS class from my plugin but I am not able to call properly this iOS function :

```
(id) init:(void*)view RemoteParticipants:(unsigned int)remoteParticipants LogFileFilter:(const char*)logFileFilter LogFileName:(const char*)logFileName
```

From the nativescript command

```
TNS_DEBUG_METADATA_PATH="$(pwd)/metadata" tns build ios
```

I am able to see the signature that NativeScript is waiting for :

```
- Name:            'init:ViewStyle:RemoteParticipants:LogFileFilter:LogFileName:'
        JsName:          initViewStyleRemoteParticipantsLogFileFilterLogFileName
        Filename:        [...].h
        Module:          
        [...]
        Type:            Method
        Signature:       
          - Type:            Instancetype
          - Type:            Pointer
            PointerType:     
              Type:            Void
          - Type:            Enum
            Name:            VCConnectorViewStyle
          - Type:            UInt
          - Type:            CString
          - Type:            CString
```

When I give a void pointer it's working, however the function is waiting for a view to display a video so the function is doing its job but I see nothing on my iOS app. For now I have my UIView :

```
this.nativeView = UIView.alloc().initWithFrame(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds)
initViewStyleRemoteParticipantsLogFileFilterLogFileName(this.nativeView, [...])
```

It does not works, as I have an error :

```
 ERROR Error: Value is not a pointer.
```

**Question : How to get a pointer from my UIView ?**

Comment: Which SDK / Framework you are actually trying to implement, do they have the docs for Objective C?

Comment: @Manoj I'm trying to implement Vidyo developer.vidyo.io/#/documentation/4.1.25.30. They do have documentation in Objective C and a sample. They pass the UIView pointer. However I am not able to pass in the NativeScript UIView as a pointer to give it to Vidyo

Comment: Maybe you should look for `interop.Reference`: https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/ios-runtime/types/C-Pointers

Comment: Hi @Juky thank you for your help, I already tried but I don't know what to give to interop.Reference() since every examples are for string / integer and not complex objects like UIView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution, with some luck to be honest :

```
this.nativeView = UIView.alloc().initWithFrame(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds)
let ref = new interop.Reference(interop.Pointer, this.nativeView)
initViewStyleRemoteParticipantsLogFileFilterLogFileName(ref, [...])
```

Quite straightforward but the documentation was not clear about it. Hope this helps